# How do I install this src.tar.gz file?

Tags: installation, games, source-code

I have heard that installing or running .tar.gz files is possible. This is a source code, also and if there is a difference I should be told about it. The game is  http://www.knightsgame.org.uk/files/knights_022_src.tar.gz. Success would be great. This is a good game, It would be appreciated. ;)

Followed mikewhatever's directions below but ran into:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libsdl1.2-dev' instead of 'libsdl-dev'
Note, selecting 'libfontconfig1-dev' instead of 'libfontconfig-dev'
build-essential is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.2) but 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgnutls-dev but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
     libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfontconfig1 (= 2.8.0-3ubuntu9) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
     libsdl1.2-dev : Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`apt-get autoclean` removed the held packages.

This sends me looking for repositories but the curl and libcurl repositories are without  libcurl4-gnutls-dev.

Comment: Here is a [good howto](http://www.howtogeek.com/105413/). The list of dependencies is [here](http://www.knightsgame.org.uk/manual/building.html).

Comment: @mikewhatever helpful thanks, I am having trouble with translation from french Ubuntu.

Comment: Difficult to understand? Check out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've not installed the game, and don't know if it works, but the steps to build that particular source code should be as follows:

- Extracting

Right-click the downloaded file, select 'Extract here'.

- Installing dependencies

Open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t in Ubuntu), and the command below. It will install quite a few additional files.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libboost-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev libsdl-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig-dev
```

- Installing

Still in a terminal window, change to the source directory with `cd knights_022_src`, then run `make`, and wait. If it finishes without errors, run `sudo make install`.